# How to view Macro definition value in executable

Tags: c++, c

Been years since I've coded in C/C++ so sorry about the newbie'ish question.  I have codebase that compiles differently based upon configurations that are defined via #defines, which can be provided as args to the makefile.  Is there a way to encode these #defines so I can look at an executable and see what the define was - e.g.

```
int main() {
  #ifdef CONFIG_A
    init_config_a();
  #endif
  #ifdef CONFIG_B
    init_config_b();
  #endif
}

#ifdef CONFIG_A
void init_config_a() {
  // do something
}
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_B
void init_config_b() {
  // do something for B
}
#endif
```

How can I tell if a given executable was created with config A or config B.  One hack is to look for symbols that are only compiled based upon the definitions (e.g. init_config_a) but that's pretty ugly.

EDIT: Sorry I neglected an important piece of info: the program is actually compiled to run on an embedded system so I can't easily just add a switch or some other mechanism to run the program locally.

Comment: You could use a command line switch like compilers do with `-v` to make that information available.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see which macro was defined you execute the binary or when you disassemble the binary?

Comment: If you don't want the command line switch or an API / message handler, have a const string like CONFIG_NAME that is defined to different values by whatever config is active.

Comment: I think your best bet is to dump symbol table from an executable and look for init_conft_a or init_config_b. Another possibility is to run a standalone preprocssor on your code or use a corresponding qualifier of the compiler. Then you can see the code which compiler would compile.

Comment: why do not you create intermediate file with compiler option --save-temps to see how macros are resolved and see the pre-processed code's final state without defining extra string etc.

Comment: If the executable was compiled with optimizations enabled it may well be that the compiler inlined `init_config_[ab]` and there is no symbol in the executable. If someone removed the debug symbols function names will also not be available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is not really precise on how you really want to get the information once you have the binary. As solution that does not involved disassembly would be having a struct with that information and initialize it when you want to print that information. Perhaps something as trivial as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct buildinfo {
    int CONFIG_A;
    int CONFIG_B;
};

void get_build_info(struct buildinfo *info)
{
    if(info == NULL)
        return;

    memset(info, 0, sizeof *info);

#ifdef CONFIG_A
    info->CONFIG_A = 1;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_B
    info->CONFIG_B = 1;
#endif

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if(argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-v") == 0)
    {
        struct buildinfo info;
        get_build_info(&info);
        printf("build info: CONFIG_A: %s, CONFIG_B: %s\n",
                info->CONFIG_A ? "yes" : "no",
                info->CONFIG_B ? "yes" ; "no");

        return 0;
    }


    ...


    return 0;
}
```

I you don't want to analyse the  binary, then you can execute `./yourprogram -v` and see the information printed on screen.

Comment: Looks pretty complicated. Why the struct? And why pass a pointer instead of just returning it? You can have the same with `enum buildinfo {A,B}; buildinfo get_build_info() { #ifdef CONFIG_A return A; #else return B; #endif}`. However I am pretty sure that the function call will be optimized away (inlining and constant propagation) and the executable will just contain the output of two string constants.

Comment: @Jens *And why pass a pointer instead of just returning it* because I don't like returning a struct and if I had to return a pointer  to struct, I would have to allocate memory, etc. Passing an uninitialized struct to the init function is the easiest thing to do....

Comment: @Jens hey this is just an example, not a *must do this way or die* answer. Who knows if the OP needs more build information, CFlags, LDflags and how knows what else. Anyway the info may cover different types, bools, ints, strings, etc. So having a struct for that doesn't seem to me a bad idea. If you have another suggestion, write an answer with your idea.

Comment: It may be a C vs. C++ thing, but I don't like output arguments. Why do you have to allocate memory to return the struct? You can just return it by value. The compiler will allocate memory on the callers stack and even elide the copy. It's a very common optimization that compilers are doing for years. The function would be more robust, does not have side-effects (and thus easier to reason about), the code gets simpler, no need to check any parameter for `null` ...

Comment: @Jens yes indeed, it may be a C vs C++ thing. I personally don't like to return a struct, specially when they are big (let's say some hundreds/thousands bytes long). I think it's more efficient to pass pointers (always a fix sized) to structs rather than the structs themselves. In C we don't have copy constructors, operator overloading and all those nice C++ features. That's why I avoid returning structs.

Comment: Thanks - you're correct that I was not precise enough.  This is actually for a program that is cross-compiled and run on an embedded system, so I can't just run it on my system.  But I appreciate your solution.

Comment: @farhadf but theoretically you could run it on your target and see the output there :)

Comment: @pablo yes, but I was hoping to to be able to check the binary prior to downloading to device, connecting serial port, etc

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way will be to name the binary based upon the define used.
2. If you want to tell whether the binary was build with `CONFIG_A` or `CONFIG_B` just by inspection. On  possible approach could be the following.
   Put a signature depending on the configuration at a specific address (will work at any address too). e.g.

   ```
   int main() {
   #ifdef CONFIG_A
   // this sign can be put at specific address with #pragma
   const char sign[]="CONFIG_A";
   init_config_a();
   #elif defined(CONFIG_B)   // only one shall be defined at a time 
   // this sign can be put at specific address with #pragma
   const char sign[]="CONFIG_B";
   init_config_b();
   #endif
   }
   ```

When you open the binary in a text editor you will be able to see the sign in ASCII view.

Comment: You should do something with `sign`, otherwise the compiler may just optimize it away.

Comment: Good point Jens.  This is not seem that different from the symbol table/strings approach...